# Jquery Field Validation

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to validate the textfield while clicking on sumbit button using Jquery but unfortunately field s are not validating    here is my Html and js code

```
<span id="as_input_list">
<dt><label for="id_video_id" class="after_none">Video Link <span class="s_round_black">1</span></label></dt>
<dd>
<input name="video_id" id="id_video_id_1" class="textField long as_video_input" type="text" value="" onkeyup="remove_color($(this));">
</dd>
</span>
<dd>
<a href="#1" id="as_addmore" onclick="add_more_video();" style="float:right;" >Add more</a>
</dd>
<dt>&nbsp;</dt>
<dd><div class="buttons" style="padding-top: 10px;">
<input class="inputsubmit on" id="" name="" value="Add Video"  type="submit" onclick="save_video();" >
<input class="inputsubmit off" id="" name="" value="Cancel" type="button" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='/staff/videos/?message=oc'"></div>
</dd>
```

This is My js File i am using some existing code and i am new in javascript also .

```
function save_video(){
    var videos = '';
    var is_error = false;
    var url_match = /https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?/;

$('.as_input_list').each(function(index){
    if (index == 0) {
        if(!url_match.test($(this).val()) || $.trim($(this).val()) == ''){
            $(this).addClass('error'); 
            is_error = true;
            $(this).parent().prev('dt').children('label').addClass('error'); 
            $(this).parent().prev('dt').children('label').children('.s_round_black').css('background-color','red'); 
        }
        else{
            videos = $(this).attr('name') + '=' + $.trim($(this).val()) ;
        }
    }
    else{
        if(!url_match.test($(this).val()) || $.trim($(this).val()) == '' ){ 
            is_error = true;
            $(this).addClass('error'); 
            $(this).parent().prev('dt').children('label').addClass('error'); 
            $(this).parent().prev('dt').children('label').children('.s_round_black').css('background-color','red');
        }
        else{
            videos += '&' + $(this).attr('name') + '=' + $.trim($(this).val()) ;
        }
    }
});

if(is_error){
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Where is your `save_video()` function called from? And are those fields in a `<form>` element?

Comment: @ yup fields are form element  Now Check I am calling save_video()  from submit button

Comment: you don't need to write validations yourself like this. You can simply use Jquery validation plugin. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: Aside from whatever errors might be in your function, you should trigger the validation from `$("#your form id").submit()` - return false to cancel submission or true to continue - rather than doing it from the button's click event.

Answer (score 0):

You declared the id for the `<span id="as_input_list">`, but in the js part you calling it by class `$('.as_input_list')`.

Try change

```
$('.as_input_list')
```

to

```
$('#as_input_list')
```